# Multiplex scp copies

Tags: shell

Using scp only is there a way to copy multiple files at the same time? I have two 40G folders on a RHEL box that I want to copy over to my ESXi box. Rsync is out of option and scp is the only thing available.

If I use:

```
scp /files root@esx:/vmfs/volumes/storage
```

It will copy File_1 40G first and then once this finishes, it will start to copy File_2

I want to initiate both the 40G copy at the same time. I tried:

```
scp /file1 root@esx:/vmfs/volumes/storage && scp /file2 root@esxi:/vmfs/volume/storage
```

Still no go. One way I am using now is tar.zip the two folders and then moving them over. And then untar on the destination. Not efficient though.

Any thoughts? Thanks much

Comment: In theory, each file would copy half as fast due to cap on network speed....

Answer (score 1):

Execute both process parallel in the background and wait for both to finish:

```
($(scp /file1 root@esx:/vmfs/volumes/storage) &); ($(scp /file2 root@esxi:/vmfs/volume/storage) &);
```

Comment: I did `scp -r /run/media/tse-admin/Lab-Files/Lab-Templates/AD-vCloud root@10.109.8.39:/vmfs/volumes/Main-DS & scp /run/media/tse-admin/Lab-Files/Lab-Templates/Jump-Cloud root@10.109.8.39:/vmfs/volumes/Main-DS & wait` 

It said. `[5] 26641  [6] 26642`  however there is no copy being initiated when I check for files on destination. Something wrong in my command?

Comment: My bad...check the new command running both in subshells.

Comment: Well:
`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'`

Comment: Very strange... Did you copy the exact command I posted? Please try again!

Comment: But each scp needs a password when reaching the remote host? Do you use sshpass?.. If not, then both commands run forever in the background indefinitely waiting for the password.

Comment: Yep the command was the same you provided. sshpass is what I will be considering now. I will give that a go.